# limit php script (fetch all photos in a directory) to 7

Tags: php

can someone please help, i am using a script in php to fetch all the photos in a directory, but i want it to limit it to only fetch 7 images in total, the ones it select can be random.

can anyone suggest a way i can do this thanks.

```
<?php if (isset($_SESSION['user_id'])) { 
        if ($user['id'] == $_SESSION['user_id']){
            if ($user['account_type'] == "Escort"){ ?>
<div class="profile_photos_drop"><iframe src="includes/mod_photo_uploads/small_pics.php" width="184" height="194" scrolling="no" style="overflow:hidden; margin-top:-4px; margin-left:-4px; border:none;"></iframe></div><? } } } ?>
 <?php
$profile_bits = get_profile_bits();
while ($profile = mysql_fetch_array($profile_bits)) { 
$dirname = "./data/photos/".$profile_id."/";
$images = scandir($dirname);
$ignore = Array("_cover.jpg", "_default.jpg", "_starlight.jpg", "_starlight_thumb.jpg", "thumb_pic1.jpg", "thumb_pic2.jpg", "thumb_pic3.jpg", "thumb_pic4.jpg", "thumb_pic5.jpg", "thumb_pic6.jpg", "thumb_pic7.jpg", "thumb_pic8.jpg", "thumb_pic9.jpg", "thumb_pic10.jpg", "thumb_pic11.jpg", "thumb_pic12.jpg", "thumb_pic13.jpg", "thumb_pic14.jpg", "thumb_pic15.jpg", "thumb_pic16.jpg");
foreach($images as $curimg){
if(!in_array($curimg, $ignore) && preg_match("/\.jpg$/i", $curimg)) {
echo "<a href=\"".$dirname.$curimg."\" rel=\"shadowbox\" title=\"<strong>{$profile['display_name']}'s Photo's</strong>\"><img src='".$dirname.$curimg."' class=\"profile_photos\" width=\"170\" height=\"150\" ></a>";
};
} 
}
?>
```

Comment: `$images = array_slice(scandir($dirname), 0, 7)`. You are iterating over an array, it's not unreasonable to think that if you only want to iterate over 7 items you should simply crop the array to 7 items. Which makes me believe you didn't even try.

Answer (score 0):

Use a counter in your foreach loop and break out of the loop when it equals 7, like this:

```
<?php if (isset($_SESSION['user_id'])) { 
        if ($user['id'] == $_SESSION['user_id']){
            if ($user['account_type'] == "Escort"){ ?>
<div class="profile_photos_drop"><iframe src="includes/mod_photo_uploads/small_pics.php" width="184" height="194" scrolling="no" style="overflow:hidden; margin-top:-4px; margin-left:-4px; border:none;"></iframe></div><? } } } ?>
 <?php
$profile_bits = get_profile_bits();
while ($profile = mysql_fetch_array($profile_bits)) { 
$dirname = "./data/photos/".$profile_id."/";
$images = scandir($dirname);
$ignore = Array("_cover.jpg", "_default.jpg", "_starlight.jpg", "_starlight_thumb.jpg", "thumb_pic1.jpg", "thumb_pic2.jpg", "thumb_pic3.jpg", "thumb_pic4.jpg", "thumb_pic5.jpg", "thumb_pic6.jpg", "thumb_pic7.jpg", "thumb_pic8.jpg", "thumb_pic9.jpg", "thumb_pic10.jpg", "thumb_pic11.jpg", "thumb_pic12.jpg", "thumb_pic13.jpg", "thumb_pic14.jpg", "thumb_pic15.jpg", "thumb_pic16.jpg");
$counter = 0;
foreach($images as $curimg){
if(!in_array($curimg, $ignore) && preg_match("/\.jpg$/i", $curimg)) {
echo "<a href=\"".$dirname.$curimg."\" rel=\"shadowbox\" title=\"<strong>{$profile['display_name']}'s Photo's</strong>\"><img src='".$dirname.$curimg."' class=\"profile_photos\" width=\"170\" height=\"150\" ></a>";
$counter++;
if($counter == 7) break;
};
} 
}
?>
```

I've only added those 3 lines: "$counter = 0;", "$counter++" and "if($counter == 7) break;"

Comment: so, whats up @Bear John? :-)